# Error message by adding an arrow

Tags: arrows

I have the following code:

```
\listfiles
\documentclass[oneside,12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
%\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[fixamsmath,disallowspaces]{mathtools}
\begin{document}


\underline{Unterbrechbare Ger{\"a}te} \\
\rightarrow \text{ mit n verschiedenen Phasen (n beliebig aber fest)}  


\begin{equation*}
P_j(t, s_{j,i}) = \begin{cases}
    Q_{j,Standby} & \text{f"ur  } t < s_{j,1}   \\
        Q_{j,1}(t-s_{j,1}) & \text{f"ur  } s_{j,1} \leq t \leq s_{j,1} + p_{j,1}  \\
        Q_{j,Standby} & \text{f"ur  }   s_{j,1} + p_{j,1}  \leq t \leq s_{j,2} \\
        Q_{j,2}(t-s_{j,2}) & \text{f"ur  } s_{j,2} \leq t \leq s_{j,2} + p_{j,2}  \\
        Q_{j,Standby} & \text{f"ur  }  s_{j,2} + p_{j,2} \leq t \leq s_{j,3} \\
        .  & \\
        .  & \\
        .  & \\
        Q_{j,Standby} & \text{f"ur  } \text{f"ur  } s_{j,n-1} + p_{j,n-1} \leq t \leq s_{j,n} \\
        Q_{j,n}(t-s_{j,n}) & \text{f"ur  } s_{j,n} \leq t \leq s_{j,n} + p_{j,n}  \\
        Q_{j,Standby} & \text{f"ur  } \text{f"ur  } s_{j,n}  + p_{j,n} \leq t  \\
  \end{cases} \\
 \end{equation*}

 mit
 \begin{align*}
 &s_{j,1} < s_{j,2} < ... < s_{j,n}  \quad \forall j \in J_u \\
    &s_{j,n} + p_{j,n} < d_j \quad \forall j \in J_u \\
     &s_{j,1} > r_j \quad \forall j \in J_u \\
    &s_{j,i} + p_{j,i+1} < s_{j,i+1} \quad \forall i \in \{1,2, ... , n-1\} \quad \forall j \in J_u \\
    \end{align*}

\end{document}
```

If I compile that I get two errors (both of the type: `Missing $ inserted`) because of the `\rightarrow` command at the beginning. How can I add this arrow without getting an error.

Furthermore I do not understand why the position of this arrow (I can see that by letting TeXnicCenter create a PDF) and the position of the word "mit" which seperates the two parts of this document are not at the same horizontal position like the underlyned heading. They are shifted a little bit to the left.

Comment: Welcode to TeX.SX! `\rightarrow` is a math mode command, so you should do `$\rightarrow$`, in that place (not when using the arrow in a formula). Also ``\\`` is not to be used before `\end{equation}` and no blank line should precede `mit`.

Comment: Okay, i have fixed the problem with the arrow but the other problem remains. I have eliminated the blank line before the word "mit" but this has not changed the problem. It is still the case that the arrow and the word "mit" do not start at the same horizontal position like the heading

Comment: You're forgetting `\noindent` before `\underline`. Note that underlining is a device that typographers frown on.

Answer (score 3):

`\rightarrow` is a math mode command. To get the underlined word flush left, use `\noindent` (but avoid underlining, as a general rule).

Note that “Standby” should be in upright font (with `\mathrm`) and that `\text` in the header has no purpose. Also use `\dots` instead of `...`.

```
\documentclass[oneside,12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
%\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[fixamsmath,disallowspaces]{mathtools}
\begin{document}

\noindent
\underline{Unterbrechbare Ger{\"a}te} \\
$\rightarrow$ mit $n$ verschiedenen Phasen ($n$ beliebig aber fest)


\begin{equation*}
P_j(t, s_{j,i}) = \begin{cases}
    Q_{j,\mathrm{Standby}} & \text{f"ur  } t < s_{j,1}   \\
        Q_{j,1}(t-s_{j,1}) & \text{f"ur  } s_{j,1} \leq t \leq s_{j,1} + p_{j,1}  \\
        Q_{j,\mathrm{Standby}} & \text{f"ur  }   s_{j,1} + p_{j,1}  \leq t \leq s_{j,2} \\
        Q_{j,2}(t-s_{j,2}) & \text{f"ur  } s_{j,2} \leq t \leq s_{j,2} + p_{j,2}  \\
        Q_{j,\mathrm{Standby}} & \text{f"ur  }  s_{j,2} + p_{j,2} \leq t \leq s_{j,3} \\
        .  & \\
        .  & \\
        .  & \\
        Q_{j,\mathrm{Standby}} & \text{f"ur  } \text{f"ur  } s_{j,n-1} + p_{j,n-1} \leq t \leq s_{j,n} \\
        Q_{j,n}(t-s_{j,n}) & \text{f"ur  } s_{j,n} \leq t \leq s_{j,n} + p_{j,n}  \\
        Q_{j,\mathrm{Standby}} & \text{f"ur  } \text{f"ur  } s_{j,n}  + p_{j,n} \leq t  \\
  \end{cases} \\
 \end{equation*}

 mit
 \begin{align*}
 &s_{j,1} < s_{j,2} < \dots < s_{j,n}  \quad \forall j \in J_u \\
    &s_{j,n} + p_{j,n} < d_j \quad \forall j \in J_u \\
     &s_{j,1} > r_j \quad \forall j \in J_u \\
    &s_{j,i} + p_{j,i+1} < s_{j,i+1} \quad \forall i \in \{1,2, \dots , n-1\} \quad \forall j \in J_u \\
 \end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]